# Why I can't get data from array of singleton which I set previously?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have set JsonArray at my singleton:

```
try {
            obj.addProperty("filename", name)
            obj.addProperty("data", data)
            oldArray.add(obj)

            sn.array = oldArray

            getImages()
        } catch (e: JsonIOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

and then I try to remove item of this object from my RV list, but I can't get any value of this array because it is empty:

```
Singleton sn = new Singleton();
JsonArray array = sn.getArray();

if (Objects.requireNonNull(array).size() > 0) {
}
```

I can't understand why it happens and how I solve this problem. At singleton I see this data, but also when I'm trying to get it I see that array is totally empty. Why does it happen and what I did wrong again? Maybe my jsonArray value has wrong field at my singleton:

```
var array:JsonArray? = JsonArray()
```

hope the problem is easier than it looks for me :)

Comment: show whole singleton

Comment: whole singleton is too big and contains a lot of useless info for you, maybe you will say what I have to show at this singleton?

Comment: at what step do you fill the array ?

Comment: at try-catch from my question

Comment: yes but it is in some kind of a function or constructor ?

Comment: in a function of my activity, I can post it also

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Dont post all your code, post the *relevant* parts please. And seriously: never ever post code that doesn't even compile. You want others to spend their time to help you, so you please spend the time required to come up with content we can actually help with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a singleton is that you have just one instance of the class. In your case you create a new instance of the singleton class each time you access it. Obviously, it comes up as null. What you should do instead is have something like this:

```
class Singleton {
    public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    // The rest of its members
}
```

And then you access it via:

```
Singleton.INSTANCE
```

That way you only ever have one instance of your class. Of course, there are other ways to make a singleton in Java, this is just the simplest one.

In Kotlin you can write simply

```
object Singleton {
    // Singleton members
}
```

Comment: I have singleton at my app

Comment: If you write `Singleton sn = new Singleton();`, you most definitely don't have a singleton.

Comment: can you suggest instance value for kotlin based singleton?

Comment: Are you writing in Kotlin or in Java? The code you've posted is Java. In Kotlin there's a built-in support for singletons (`object`). You can look it up in the documentation.

Comment: singleton is in kotlin, java code is from adapter of rv, but right now I have moved to kotlin

Comment: In java, you might want to use an enum with a single instance these days.

Comment: @GhostCat Yeah, that's the best way probably because in this case you have guarantees by the language, however, given the level of the OP I decided not to introduce additional details.

Comment: @Malcolm sneaky